# Adding additional columns to a JPA query with JOINs

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a query which wants all the fields in the Person table.
Person has a 1:1 with Job over a relationship called current job.  I would like to bring in two fields from the Job table, jobTitle and startDate.  Can I type this query to Person and then bring in the two extra fields in the same database hit or can I only do this in JPA query language?

Comment: Yes, you can build an Entiy taht is the result of an "complex" request. By "conplex" I mean everything more complex than "Select X From Y Where a = b".

Comment: @Zorglube thanks can you send on a link or something? Thanks

Comment: I'm looking, but no more than 2 min, because it's bulit-in in JPA so you really shoul read the documentation.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-mapping-single-entity-to-multiple-tables

Comment: Do you need the data just for this specific query? Do you have a DTO class that you want to return?